# How would you convert this string to JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to serialize this string into a multidimensional array using JSON.  How would you do it?

> {frmb[0][cssClass]=textarea&frmb[0][required]=true&frmb[0][values]=para&frmb[1][cssClass]=radio&frmb[1][required]=true&frmb[1][title]=rdo&frmb[1][values][2][value]=one&frmb[1][values][2][baseline]=true&frmb[1][values][3][value]=two&frmb[1][values][3][baseline]=false&frmb[2][cssClass]=input_text&frmb[2][required]=false&frmb[2][values]=text&frmb[3][cssClass]=checkbox&frmb[3][required]=true&frmb[3][title]=chk&frmb[3][values][2][value]=chk+1&frmb[3][values][2][baseline]=true&frmb[3][values][3][value]=chk+2&frmb[3][values][3][baseline]=false&frmb[4][cssClass]=select&frmb[4][required]=false&frmb[4][multiple]=true&frmb[4][title]=sel&frmb[4][values][2][value]=sel1&frmb[4][values][2][baseline]=true&frmb[4][values][3][value]=sel2&frmb[4][values][3][baseline]=false&form_id=undefined}

**EDIT:**
The multidimensionality is really screwing me up on converting this string into JSON.  I tried stripping out the brackets to get a list of indices for the array, but rebuilding the array in a useful manner has been the biggest challenge.

So I have been doing:

```
private static List<string> StripBrackets(string input)
        {
            var ret = new List<string>();
            var indx = 0;
            do
            {
                input = input.TrimStart('[');
                indx = input.IndexOf(']');
                if(indx !=-1)
                {
                    var newVal = input.Substring(0, indx);
                    ret.Add(newVal);
                    input = input.Remove(0, indx+1);
                }
            } while (indx != -1);

                //-- this is where I bonked
                string[,] results = new string[ret.Count, 23];    
                foreach (var r in ret)
                {                    
                }    
                 return ret;
            }
```

I've been grinding on this for a long time - hence the tired/limited question.  It started to feel like I was doing this the "hard way" and wanted to see if anyone enlightened had any better ideas.  TIA

Comment: You can use json2 to serialize in javascript: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: @Mansfield it is not valid JSON.  Will json2 convert it?

Comment: If you can list what you have tried and your thoughts are we could really help more, there's no point in any of us spouting off arbitrary answers without knowing why you're struggling with this problem. Alternatively asking for someone to design an entire approach for you is not really a good fit for Q&A because no one answer is correct without more details from you. I know how I'd do this, but I don't know what your struggling with.

Comment: If it's not valid JSON, you're going to have to do it manually anyway. But once you've made the string syntactically valid, json2 will convert it to an array easily.

Comment: in javascript: `var frmb=[];eval(str.replace("&",";"));result = JSON.stringify(frmb)`

Comment: @ratchetfreak great idea, make this the answer; apparently he's handling this on the serverside but he could probably do that clientside and pass the object to the server, perhaps. Alternatively he could use a serverside serializer treating it as JSON with a few string replacements like replacing = with :, but that might get trickier. Also made my -1 a +1 for your edit, thanks!

Comment: @ratchetfreak your answer ultimately helped push me in the right direction.  TY

Comment: That string in particular? Just that string? I'd hand-edit it with a text editor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anyone recommend how to convert this string to a multidimensional array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368874/can-anyone-recommend-how-to-convert-this-string-to-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Where is this string coming from & how is it getting generated?  Serializing it when you still have a structure would be far easier than trying to recreate it from this mess.  It looks like it might be a query string - does your web environment not already parse it for you?

Comment: @SeanMcSomething I'm trying to port this jquery plugin to C#: http://www.botsko.net/blog/2009/04/07/jquery-form-builder-plugin/ It uses this plugin to iterate the DOM tree to build the post values to pass back to the server. http://www.botsko.net/blog/2009/01/29/jquery_serialize_list_plugin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @ratchetfreak's comment:

```
var str = "{frmb...";

//sanitize string
str = str.substring(1, str.length-1); //remove braces
str = str.replace(/\[([a-z]+)\]/gi, '["$1"]'); //enclose non-numeric keys in double quotes
str = str.replace(/=([^&]+)/g, '="$1"'); //enclose values in double quotes
str = str.replace(/"(true|false)"/g, "$1"); //remove double quotes around boolean values
str = str.replace(/&/g, ";"); //replace all ampersands with semi-colons

//initialize "frmb"
var frmb = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5 /* a guess as to how long "frmb" will be */; i++){
  var values = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < 5 /* a guess as to how long each "values" field will be */; j++){
    values.push({});
  }
  frmb.push({values:values});
}

//evaluate as Javascript
eval(str);

//marshal to string
var result = JSON.stringify(frmb);
```

The part that makes this solution difficult to make general-purpose is that you need to initialize "frmb".  For example, you can't call `frmb[0].cssClass` without first initializing `frmb` to an array and then adding an object to that array with `push()`.  So, you need to estimate how large you think `frmb` will be, as well as how large each `values` sub-array will be.

Comment: Thank you.  Was still struggling a bit with this, but you have gotten me to a resolution.

Comment: This almost works, but it's not deserializing into an object because the field values can be either a string or an array. Do you know how to avoid this? [**"values":"Description"**,"cssClass":"textarea","required":false},{**"values"**:[{"value":"Extra%20Cheese","baseline":false},{"value":"Pepperoni","baseline":false},{"value":"Beef","baseline":false}],"cssClass":"checkbox","required":false,"title":"Whats%20on%20your%20pizza%3F"}]

Comment: Nevermind, this seems to do the trick:  http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx